# How can I change the legend's location in a pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For a report I am preparing several figures that I exported from Matlab using the matlab2tikz script. However, the location of the legend does not please me. Here is an example plot:

[image]

I want to move the legend into the bottom right (souh east) corner. I tried doing this applying the command `legend pos=south east` as explained in the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), page 117. However, this does not change anything but rather delivers a `finished with exit code 1` message.

**Did anything change unnotedly in the pgfplots package? Or how do I properly move the legend?**

Minimal example that produces `exit code 1`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
width=0.45\textwidth,
height=0.2\textheight,
xmin=0, xmax=300,
ymin=-2e+06, ymax=1e+07,
legend entries={Analytic solution,GPS data,Kalman filtered},
legend style={nodes=right},
legend pos= south east]

\addplot [color=blue, solid]
coordinates{ (0,7e+06) (0.1,7.0007e+06) (0.2,7.0014e+06) };

\addplot [color=green, solid]
coordinates{ (0,6.99999e+06) (0.1,7.00071e+06) (0.2,7.00143e+06) };

\addplot [color=red, solid]
coordinates{ (0,0) (0.1,7.00071e+06) (0.2,7.00174e+06) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works without problems for me (but the x axis range is wrong).

Comment: Does it display the legend in the bottom right corner? It definitely does not work in my machine. The x-axis range might be wrong but is not in the real case. I just removed a lot of data for this minimal example

Comment: Also works on my system, and the legend does show up in the bottom right corner. Maybe you could try clearing aux files? updating your TeX installation?

Comment: I use TeXLive2009 and cleared all my .aux fles :(. This is extremely weired. Maybe some bad interaction with other packages?

Comment: Update: I just tried to compile one of the examples from the manual. Does not work! This is extremely strange. I use a fresh installation of TeXLive2009 from the package manager in Ubuntu.
Probably this question should be closed because it seems to be a specific probkem.

Comment: @Ingo If the minimal example above produces the error, there shouldn’t be any interaction with other packages. @Philipp, @Juan Did you use TL 2009?

Comment: @Caramdir I use TL 2010. Maybe some bug has been fixed during the last year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example compiles fine with TeX Live 2010. With the Ubuntu 10.10 packages (texlive-full-2009-10, i.e. TL2009), I get the error

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/legend pos' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

You could try to install a new version of pgfplots from CTAN.

Since the Ubuntu TeX packages often have bugs and do not get updates between Ubuntu versions, I would recommend to just install the current version of TeX Live directly from http://tug.org/texlive/. Post a question if you need help with that (hint: the global $PATH is set in /etc/environment in Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer. I contacted the package's author and he also wrote me that I need a new version. To be honest I was sure that I had the latest teXLive version, having the latest Ubuntu version. Turns out that is not the case.

"Package: pgfplots 2009/02/14 Version 1.2.2"

Is the **really** old version that comes with 10.10.

Comment: I guess the official release of tl2010 was too late to make it into ubuntu 10.10.