# tikz: plotting a one column file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex

I use tikz/pgf to plot plots with data from a file. This works perfectly fine if I have at least to columns in the file that I can choose from. However, I have a rather huge file with just one column. This should represent the y-axis. The x-axis should be just the number of the entry/row/line. I wonder why gnuplot can handle this easily but I have problems getting this run with tikz/pgf. Here is one approach that does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot plot file {lala};
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here's another one that does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table[y index=0] {lala};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

'lala' looks like this:

```
10
9
3
2
```

It should be an easy one, but all the examples I find are with at least two columns.

Thanks in advance,

o

/edit: Sorry, I forgot about the error message:

```
Runaway argument?
\else \expandafter \pgfplots@addplotimpl@file@readall \fi \fi \pgfplots@coord@s
tream@end \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgfplots@addplotimpl@file@parsesingle was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.15
```

/edit2: After Jake's comment, I run the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {lala.dat};
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it gives me the following error message:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/x expr' and I am going to
 ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

[This person has the same error message.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/how-can-i-change-the-legends-location-in-a-pgfplot) It is obviously because of my old texlive (2009) which is installed on my Linux Mint 12 (Ubuntu 11.10). I'll try to install texlive2010.

Comment: You should install TeXLive 20 *12*, not 2010 `=)`

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I even downloaded it! Thanks for your help! I will see if your solution works when I got this installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, PGFPlots assumes that the data for the x coordinates is in the first column of the file, and the data for the y coordinates is in the second column. If you want to use the row number as the x coordinate, you can use `\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=0]`. Note that you'll have to use `table` instead of `file`: The latter always uses the first column for the x and the second column for the y coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=0] {
10
9
3
2
    };
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer! Unfortunately, it breaks with another error message: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/x expr' and I am going to
 ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`. Maybe it was a misunderstanding, `lala` is the file name and 10, 9, 3, 2 the content of the file ...

Comment: @Oliver: Sorry, I should have clarified that you'll have to use `table` instead of `file` for this. I've edited my answer. Providing the file name or the table data directly doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: It does not work anyway. I always get the error message above. Do I need to include something else?

Comment: @Oliver Try `\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=0] {lala.data};`

Comment: @Oliver: Could you edit your question to include an example that gives you the error message?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks, I think its because my Ubuntu 11.10 is running texlive2009. Here is someone who as the same problem: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/how-can-i-change-the-legends-location-in-a-pgfplot]

Comment: @Oliver: Ah yes, that's probably it. You should definitely update your installation, or at least the TikZ and PGFPlots packages.

Comment: @Oliver Use TeXLive2009 in October 2010 may seem normal. Use TeXLive2009 in September 2012 is not the same thing... ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Ubuntu 11.10 is october 2011, so I was a little confused why texlive is still from 2009. Anyway, I installed now texlive2012 and it works fine now. Thanks to both of you, PaulGaborit and Jake, helping me out.

Comment: I have seen this error when you add the options to `\addplot[HERE] table[INSTEAD OF HERE]`.