# I have 3 data series and 2 different y-axis. How can I add, outside the graph, the legend for each of three series?

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, legend

Does someone know how can i change the position of my legend to right-side of my graph? I try many things but i can't. Please give me some help! Here is my code!

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{minipage}{1.3\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[ /pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, 1000 sep={}, scale only axis, xmin=2006,xmax=2012, ymin=65, ymax=125, axis y line*=left, xlabel=Year, ylabel=\color{black}$Percentage(\%)$]
    \addplot[black] coordinates {
    %Government Debt
(2006, 68.3608)
(2007, 68.0186)
(2008, 74.963)
(2009, 89.5022)
(2010, 102.7844)
(2011, 114.9962)
(2012, 121.9426)};
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}[ scale only axis, xmin=2006,xmax=2012, ymin=-15, ymax=5, axis y line*=right, axis x line=none, ylabel=\color{blue}$Percentage (\%)$]%
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Hplot}
\addlegendentry{$Debt$}
    \addplot[blue, mark=+] coordinates {
    %Total Budget Balance
    (2006, -1.5862)
(2007, -1.9186)
(2008, -5.624)
(2009, -9.7638)
(2010, -13.0882)
(2011, -8.0618)
(2012, -6.4806)};
\addlegendentry{$TBB$}
%
    \addplot[blue,mark=o] coordinates {
%Real per capita GDP growth rate
(2006, 3.7266)
(2007, 3.3016)
(2008, -0.5192)
(2009, -4.1474)
(2010, -0.4744)
(2011, -1.2876)
(2012, -2.4802)    
    };
\addlegendentry{$GDPpc GR$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
```

[image: My graph]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please shorten your title also

Comment: You should use the option `legend pos=outer north east` as described on page 208 of the pgfplots 1.11 manual. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134084/32374 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83328/32374 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4085/32374

Comment: You might also find http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture useful.

Answer (score 1):

As darthbith says, in general you would add `legend pos=outer north east` to place the legend outside the axis on the top right. In this case it will overlap with the top ticklabel on the right y-axis. A simple fix for that here is to also add `legend style={xshift=1em}`, thereby shifting it to the right a bit.

Other changes I made:

- On the second axis, change from `axis y line*=right` to `axis y line=right`. The latter also makes the ylabel move to the right side, which I would think you want, considering that you changed the colour of it.
- Instead of `\color{blue}`, I added `ylabel style={blue}`. Not a big deal I think, mostly a matter  of preference.
- Don't write the labels and legend entries in math mode, unless they're actual mathematical variables. `Percentage` and `Debt` for example are text, and should not be written as math.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  /pgf/number format/.cd, use comma,
  1000 sep={},
  scale only axis, 
  xmin=2006,
  xmax=2012, 
  ymin=65,
  ymax=125,
  axis y line*=left,
  xlabel=Year,
  ylabel=Percentage (\%)]

\addplot[black] coordinates {
    %Government Debt
(2006, 68.3608)
(2007, 68.0186)
(2008, 74.963)
(2009, 89.5022)
(2010, 102.7844)
(2011, 114.9962)
(2012, 121.9426)};
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}[
  scale only axis,
  xmin=2006,
  xmax=2012,
  ymin=-15,
  ymax=5,
  axis y line=right,
  axis x line=none,
  ylabel=Percentage (\%),
  ylabel style={blue},
  yticklabel style={blue},
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend style={xshift=1em}]%
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Hplot}
\addlegendentry{Debt}

\addplot[blue, mark=+] coordinates {
    %Total Budget Balance
    (2006, -1.5862)
(2007, -1.9186)
(2008, -5.624)
(2009, -9.7638)
(2010, -13.0882)
(2011, -8.0618)
(2012, -6.4806)};
\addlegendentry{TBB}
%
\addplot[blue,mark=o] coordinates {
%Real per capita GDP growth rate
(2006, 3.7266)
(2007, 3.3016)
(2008, -0.5192)
(2009, -4.1474)
(2010, -0.4744)
(2011, -1.2876)
(2012, -2.4802)    
    };
\addlegendentry{GDPpc GR}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```